# laravel (artisan) does not wait for inputs

Tags: laravel, command-prompt

When I enter a command in laravel installer that needs to select an option or I have to enter some value, it does not wait and passes automatically. If anyone has this problem, Guide me.
For example in Laravel:

> `laravel new <name> --jet`

It gives aborted error because it does not allow me to select an option.
is there any option in 'cmd' or laravel installer to ban inputs?
I have uninstalled and reinstalled the Laravel installer several times.

[image: laravel Error]

Comment: How is this related to Composer or NPM?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Start by explaining how you call npm, and which error you are facing

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the composer and changed the php version during the installation progress
then this issue was solved.